# Django commits to database before transaction ends

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions

I am using Django 1.10 with Postgres database and django-rest-framework. I debug my code and wherever I have `some_entity.save()`, I immediately see the changes in database. The thing is that I have `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True` and this would mean that nothing gets committed to the database until view successfully finishes. I am worried about the database integrity now- if later an exception occurs, nothing gets rolled back

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you "immediately see the changes in db" ? From inside the current transaction, that would be expected.

Comment: Well, I mean that I go line-to-line in debug mode. Whenever I pass any save method, data is immediately updated in database. I would expect that it would be committed at the end of the transaction. And if not, how will the transaction roll back in case of exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a perfectly expected behavior with database transactions.

With `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True` each request is wrapped in a database transaction, meaning a transaction is started when the request is received and is committed after a response is produced without problem.

During the transaction, you can read your own writes: that's how SQL databases work (and the contrary would be very confusing).

In most configurations though, these writes are "isolated": if they are not committed yet, they will not be visible from a concurrent request (in a distinct transaction). For more details about Transaction Isolation, look at postgresql docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html

Comment: Thank you, although this is strange for me to read. I am used to JPA and Hybernate on a project I work on. There, nothing is seen until the transaction is committed. Either they work like this, or the project is configured so, or I got mislead/mistaken.